# How can I combine ODATA [FromQuery] with additional querystring parameters?

Tags: c#, swagger, odata

We're using Swagger and ODATA in a C# .NET 7.0 REST API.
The attribute [EnableQuery] generates the ODATA inputs in the Swagger page to enable users to use the $top, $select, etc. properties.

I'd like to combine these parameters with a 'regular' querystring parameter. For example:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [Route($"/Templates/{{{nameof(templateId)}:guid}}/Sections")]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid templateId) { 
        // stuff
    }
```

Only the ODATA inputs are rendered, but not an input for the `templateId` Guid.

I've tried changing the route attribute syntax and value, adding the route to the HttpGet attribute, and also prefixing the `Guid templateId` with various attributes. Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax of Route attribute should be in a format

```
[Route("/templates/{templateId:guid}/Sections")]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same, just a different syntax. The double {{ and }} is the syntax to escape them and it results in a single { and }. The third { and } are for the string interpolation to switch from string to variable notation.